# ERROR: syntax error at or near "site" in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql-9.3

I am creating a stored procedure which will accept array or record as argument.

```
  CREATE TYPE site AS(
  siteid  integer,
  packageid integer,
  status  text 
);

 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION packageinfo(IN
info  site[]
)RETURNS VARCHAR  AS $$
DECLARE
    info_element  site;
BEGIN
    FOREACH info_element IN ARRAY info
    LOOP
        INSERT INTO sitepackage(
            siteid,
            packageid,
            status
        ) VALUES(
            info_element.siteid,
            info_element.packageid,
            info_element.status
        );
    END LOOP;
    RETURN 'OK';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

But it is giving an 
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "site"
LINE 11:         info_element  site;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With statement `language SQL` you are defining your function as an SQL function. The `DECLARE` block is part of the structure of PL/pgSQL functions so you have to create the function with `LANGUAGE plpgsql`.

More info from the documentation:

- [35.4. Query Language (SQL) Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xfunc-sql.html)
- [40.2. Structure of PL/pgSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-structure.html)